# lftp bi directional syncing

Tags: linux, bash, sync, lftp

How to sync directories on two different machines? If I change/add/delete a file on the windows machine, it should be changed/added/deleted on the linux machine and vice versa.

I **have to** use `lftp` to connect with the windows machine, I don't have `ssh` access and I can not execute commands from the windows machine.

That is my **script** so far, which will be running **on the linux server**:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='ftp://windows.server:21'
USER='myuser'
PASS='mypass'
TARGETFOLDER='/linux-server-folder'
SOURCEFOLDER='/windows-server-folder'

lftp -f "
set ftp:ssl-allow true 
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ftp:ssl-protect-list true
set ssl:verify-certificate true
open $HOST
login $USER $PASS
"
```

Comment: Assuming the Windows machine uses plain FTP and not something exotic, can't you just use `rsync` over ftp instead of `lftp`?

Comment: The data and login data should be transferred encrypted. So I can only use `lftp`.